# Git: My latest updates are not showing in desktop version

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

as the title says i'm having a little problem with my Git Project.

Everything was working flawlessly, me and my friend worked in this project in my home and his home. Then i got to my job and i could download git and clone it here and worked just fine aswell. When i got in my college i could download and work there with no problems at all.

When i go to my repository page on github, my latest update IS there, but if i open the application on my home, job or college, my latest updates isn't there anymore and when i try to sync it says it have merge conflicts and i can't do that.

I already discarded my changes and tried to sync to get the updated version from the online repo, but didn't work.
I already downloaded the zip from my online repo and didn't worked aswell.

The app is showing on the "history" tab that my last push was 21 hours ago, but this is already an old one and the last one is 16 hours ago and it's not even showing in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the fix.

Right click on the repository i wanted in the app, and selected to open it with git shell.

Using git shell, just type:

```
git pull origin
```

then it'll refresh